# Observe back to current thread

Tags: c#, concurrency, system.reactive

I'm trying to schedule an observable on a new thread and get the result back on the current thread.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log("init");

            Observable.Return(0)
                .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
                .Do(_ => Log("Do1 method"))
                .ObserveOn(CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance)
                .Do(_ => Log("Do2 method"))
                .Subscribe(_ => Log("subscribe method"));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Log(string label)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", label, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result that I'm getting:

```
init on 9
Do1 method on 10
Do2 method on 10
subscribe method on 10
```

Why does the Do2 method and the subscribe method are on thread #10 instead of #9? I was expecting this result:

```
init on 9
Do1 method on 10
Do2 method on 9
subscribe method on 9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see what you are trying to achieve, but this may prove difficult as you are just running in a Console app on a sync thread. 
As the main Console Thread is not an EventLoop, how would Rx be able to just "unblock" the `Console.ReadKey()` call, hijack the thread execute the `Log` method and then return waiting to the `Console.ReadKey()`?

If you were doing this in a GUI app, then the main thread would be some sort of EventLoop i.e. the Dispatcher in WPF/Silverlight.
This now easy to return control back to the "main thread" - `ObserveOn(_dispatcherScheduler)` where `_dispatcherScheduler` is the captured instance of `DispatcherScheduler`.

You can see explanations of the `Immediate` and `Current` Schedulers here - http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#SchedulersIndepth.

An alternative to your original code could be to run a third thread to act as the EventLoop using the perfectly named `EventLoopScheduler`

```
void Main()
{
    var els = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) { IsBackground = true, Name = "MyEventLoopThread"});
    els.Schedule(0, (scheduler, _)=>Run(scheduler));
}
static IDisposable Run(IScheduler mainThreadScheduler)
{
    Log("init");
    return Observable.Return(0)
        .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        .Do(_ => Log("Do1 method"))
        .ObserveOn(mainThreadScheduler)
        .Do(_ => Log("Do2 method"))
        .Subscribe(_ => Log("subscribe method"));
}
static void Log(string label)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", label, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Which creates the following (expected) output

```
init on 28
Do1 method on 29
Do2 method on 28
subscribe method on 28
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My app was working properly but I coudn't reproduce it in a console project.